# print Google Datasheets cell through a Telegram bot, print image taken form a cell as a link referal

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, google-sheets, telegram

I'm an Italian (sorry for bad English) system engineer but I accepted to help a friend so I had to achieve this goal.
He's trying to sponsor his products through Telegram but he's stingy and lazy and before investing wants to try something managed by a bot.
So I created the Telegram Bot, used his link of SpreadSheet, and tried to do this thing:
Column U is a link referral to an image and he wants to display that image, column B must be compared with a string and if it's the same then print the column A(integer), F(integer), L(string), J opens a chat with @someone if it's not the same than go to the next line.
As a  newbie I past many time reading online and trying to find the way, but I've just reached this:

```
var token ="myToken";; 
var telegramUrl = "https://api.telegram.org/bot" + token; 
var webAppUrl = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/myLinkReferal/exec"; 
var ssId = "MyssId";
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
var rangeData = sheet.getDataRange();
var lastColumn = rangeData.getLastColumn();
var lastRow = rangeData.getLastRow();
var searchRange = sheet.getRange(2,2, lastRow-1, lastColumn-1);

function getMe() {
  var url = telegramAPI + "/getMe";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function setWebhook() {
  var url = telegramAPI + "/setWebhook?url=" + webAppAPI;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function sendText(id,text) {
  var url = telegramAPI + "/sendMessage?chat_id=" + id + "&text=" + text;
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  Logger.log(response.getContentText());
}

function doPost(e) {
  Logger.log(e);
  for(i = 1; i < lastColumn; i++){
      for (j = 1; j < lastRow ; j++){
        var cell = searchRange.getCell(1,i).getValue();
        if (cell === "DISPONIBILE"){


          ****visualize a photo taken form a link in datasheet cell Ux
          print string taken from Ax
          print string taken from Ax**
          link to chat with @someone**


        }else j=lastRow;
      };
    };  
  var text = data.message.text;
  var what = data.message.text.split("-")[0]
  var who = data.message.text.split("-")[1]
  var response = "Hi " + name + ", this quote has been added to your database: " + text;
  sendText(id,response);
  SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssId).getSheets()[1].appendRow([text,response,what,who]);
  }
```

Comment: Can I ask you about the current issue of your script?

Comment: I don't know how to get the selected data and print them on Telegram... in particular this part:   visualize a photo taken form a link in datasheet cell U;  
          print string taken from A;  
          print string taken from K;  
          link to chat with @someone.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. When I could correctly understand about your current issue from your script, I would like to think of the solution. I apologize that I cannot resolve your issue soon. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.